# How can I get the value of 1 list depending on the value of another list

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I'm trying to accomplish the following and would appreciate any help.

I have a CSV file containing 2 columns, 1 a list of names and the other a list of associated IDs.

Eg.
Test1, 00001
Test2, 00002

I have read these into my program into 2 lists.
1. nameList
2. idList

I have populated the datasource of a combobox with the values of nameList.

Now, when a name is selected in the combobox and a button pressed, I would like to get the ID. So if Test1 is selected, when the button is pressed 00001 is returned where as if Test2 is selected and the button pressed, 00002 is returned.

If it helps at all, this is what im currently using to populate the Lists.

```
    public void nameCSV()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\nameList.csv"));
         List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
         List<string> idList = new List<string>();
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');

            nameList.Add(values[0]);
            idList.Add(values[1]);
        }
        cmbxName.DataSource = releaseNameList;
    }
```

Comment: In this _particular_ context, you could simply use `idList[cmbxName.SelectedIndex]`. (EDIT: Be sure to check for `SelectedIndex == -1` though as that indicates nothing is selected and would cause an error if you used it) However, consider creating a simple class to define a Name-ID pair as what you're doing here is [essentially an anti-pattern.](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/)

Comment: Tell me if you don't understand something from my answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
public void nameCSV()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\nameList.csv"));

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    tbl.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
        row["Name"]=values[0];
        row["ID"] = values[1];
        tbl.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    cmbxName.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cmbxName.ValueMember = "ID";

    cmbxName.DataSource = tbl;


}
```

You need something like that. Check properties DisplayMember and ValueMember of ComboBox.

So when the button is clicked and you want to take the Value not the display text.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       string id = cmbxName.SelectedValue;
 }
```

**N.B: Your title is misleading !**

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public void nameCSV()
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\nameList.csv"));
    Dictionary<string, int> userDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');

        userDict.Add(values[0], values[1]);
    }
    cmbxName.DataSource = userDict;
}
```

to call the value of a given user id just use the key. For example, 'Test1'

```
string Username = "Test1";
int userid;
userid = userDict[Username];
```

One note, dictionaries work better with numeric values as the key, not strings. Put in your case you're looking up the string name, so it should be this way. As long as the string lengths are short - aka no more than 10 characters. Peformance wise, you should be okay.